# Error on overload for a function that updates an object with properties of different types

Tags: typescript

I have this function that uploads an array of objects.

These are the types involved:

```
interface BLOGPOST_IMAGE {
  src:       string,
  alt:       string,
  caption:   string,
  credit:    string,
  creditSrc: string,
  sizeKb:    number,    // THESE TWO ARE number
  maxWidth:  number,    // THESE TWO ARE number
}

// AND THE FUNCTION UPDATES AN ARRAY OF THE FOLLOWING TYPE:

BLOGPOST_IMAGE[]
```

And I'm creating a function that updates one of the objects in the array:

```
function updateImage(index: number, propertyName: Extract<keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE,"sizeKb" | "maxWidth">, newValue: number): void
function updateImage(index: number, propertyName: Exclude<keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE,"sizeKb" | "maxWidth">, newValue: string): void {
  props.setBlogPost((prevState: PROJECT.BLOGPOST) => {
    const newImages = Array.from(prevState.images);
    newImages[index][propertyName] = newValue;
    return({
      ...prevState,
      images: newImages
    });
  });
}
```

That function gets an `index`, a `propertyName` and the `newValue`.

But the `newValue` should be a `number` for the following properties: `"sizeKb" | "maxWidth"` and should be a `string` for the other properties. So I've used `Extract` and `Exclude` on `keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE` to select those properties and create an overload.

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

[image]

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is not possible to get this as string and then set type to number?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, that's what I've decided to do. But still would like to know how to implement this overload, 'cause I might need it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript cannot have actual real overloads, so when you declare like this in typescript you need to provide one method declaration that can handle all the possible overloads. In your case it should look like:

```js
function updateImage(index: number, propertyName: Extract<keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE,"sizeKb" | "maxWidth">, newValue: number): void
function updateImage(index: number, propertyName: Exclude<keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE,"sizeKb" | "maxWidth">, newValue: string): void
function updateImage(index: number, propertyName: keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE, newValue: number | string): void {
...
}
```

Side note, you can simplify it a bit and get rid of the overloads like this:

```js
function updateImage<K extends keyof PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE>(
  index: number,
  propertyName: K,
  newValue: PROJECT.BLOGPOST_IMAGE[K]
): void
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The generic one really works best for this situation.